# Cache filled before reaching required amount in OpenELEC

Tags: kodi, openelec, cache

I am playing pictures and short HD videos (~40MB) **from the SD card** (not network), 24 hours a day with OpenELEC installed on Raspberry Pi. Everything was fine until the second day. Now when trying to play video it keeps alerting this: "Cache filled before reaching required amount."

I've already had set Cache settings, reading [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Modify_the_video_cache), and I thought it would be fine. What can I do now?

This is my advancedsettings.xml in Raspberry Pi B+,

```
<advancedsettings>
  <network>
    <buffermode>1</buffermode> <!--Buffer all filesystems, both internet and local-->
    <cachemembuffersize>25971520</cachemembuffersize> <!-- 25MB -->
    <readbufferfactor>2.0</readbufferfactor>
  </network>
</advancedsettings>
```

Comment: Did you read this note regarding cachebuffersize and the Raspberry Pi Value: 0 - we can use the local disk memory (typically your hard drive), which will not put any limit on the size (outside of the size of your drive). This also allows devices with low RAM, such as the Raspberry Pi, to cache more than they normally would due to the small amount of RAM they have. The cache is deleted from the local disk whenever playback is stopped. How much free memory do you have the note also mentions that you will need 3x the amount set for buffersize - so 75MB

Comment: Ok, I guess I read it but it says it will cause wear-and-tear on the SD card. I will try that value. But I need to optimize this, because they are always the same 5 videos and images rotating. It shouldn't be a problem! The RAM is divided at half between GPU and CPU

Comment: why not move the media to a removable drive even if it is a cheap flash drive or SD card instead of a more expensive and larger ext hard drive. Don't forget the old adage you can't optimize what doesn't work.

Comment: "adage"?, the sd card is new. 8gb class 10 sandisk.

Comment: adage = an old saying (usually imparting a bit of truth) or aphorism. My point was you need to worry about getting it working before you worry about optimizations. You can probably optimize cache usage by using the external drive as the cache directory as well.

Comment: is it fine to increase readbufferfactor in this case? I really need to optimize it because it is running on a local store and it shouldn't show cache alerts neither "Loading..." stuff

Comment: It does not mention any problems with the speed setting, other than it may use all of your bandwidth. Though I would suggest doing it in slow increments something like 2, 4, 8.

Comment: right. so, if I use value 0 for cachemembuffersize it will use all the ram for cache (hard drive if necessary)? ... when does cache fill? just before playing the file? while playing the previous file? sorry, many questions

Comment: from reading the notes you linked to it would seem that the cache would be full only when the disk is full (in theory anyway). and it uses the disk for caching it does not mention how or if it uses the systems memory.

Comment: so that's not the best option I think, considering it's caching in the sd card... I'm worried about reducing its life. Do you know if increasing RAM shared memory for the GPU inside config.txt would make a difference? or is there a risk on leaving the CPU without enought memory for doing its stuff?

Comment: By your own definition the system currently does not work as desired, and yet you are worried about wear and tear on the SD card (which is rated in the 100,000's in terms of access - at least). Even if it failed a backup card is cheap insurance and provides a full backup as well. Like I said make it work then worry about the wear and tear and optimizing it. As I have mentioned, once it works you can use an external drive to store the files and as your cache.

Comment: thanks for answer!. Do you think an external storage (pendrive?) would be better working at caching? Everything is working. I'm just optimizing it, because sometimes Kodi tells "Loading..." and "Cache filled before reaching..." once. I **must** avoid Loading alerts.

Comment: If you are still getting alerts "that you must avoid" then it is not really working. an external hard drive will generally have a higher level of read writes before failure, an external flash drive or SD Card is the same technology and will have a similar lifetime to the current SD Card. The only advantage is that it will not effect the system files when/if it fails.

Comment: It happened something strange. Videos encoded in h.264 (I think is the best codec for Raspberry, from what I read) says "Loading..." before playing 30mb HD videos, whereas those same videos enconded in Xvid had no problem (no Loading alert) even in larger videos. That's what I wanted. I would even need to hide those alerts, despite the fact that they were loading.

Comment: You should answer your own question.

Comment: yes.... it doesn't seem to be a great answer, but it seems it was something about the codecs. I still don't understand how videos encoded in Xvid are played smoothly even without cache settings (when there's no advancedsettings.xml). I mean, Raspberry should use some internal cache before playback...

Comment: Videos encoded in h264 (which I think it is the best codec for Raspberry, from what I read) tells "Loading..." before playing 50mb HD/1080p videos, whereas those same videos encoded in Xvid had no problem (no Loading alert) even in larger videos. That's what I wanted. I would even need to hide those alerts, despite the fact that they were loading. Any explanation or guess is welcome in comments.

Comment: This is not very useful without investigation. The change may have nothing to do with codecs, but with difference in settings you have used for Xvid and h264 files.